# Glide java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm facing an issue regarding `Glide` library.

I used couple of `multiimagepicker` API's from github
but whenever i `click` for selecting image
it crashes.
every `API` crash because of this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest; in
>   class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager' appears ...)

I'm badly stuck due to this error.
i searched on glide forum but still no proper answer found. many looking for answer of this error

Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.9.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.lolucosmin:PermissionsWrapper:version_1.2'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:BottomDialogs:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.chathuralakmal:AndroidImagePopup:1.2'
    compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
    compile 'org.aviran.cookiebar2:cookiebar2:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.github.hamsaadev:RTLMaterialSpinner:V1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'

}
```

Comment: add glide dependency into build.gradle

Comment: already added glide

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: use glide `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0` as there is some major changes in latest glide 4.x

Comment: i'm using '4.2.0 version'

Comment: https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedBottomPicker/issues/54

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya updated

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya using 4.2.0 version

Comment: @MuhammadSaad use latest `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0`

Comment: @MuhammadSaad solved this ?

Comment: Issue resolved by downloading the API and change the version of glide in that API

Comment: Have you got the perfect solution to this question then please tell me?

Comment: @Prince i downloaded the library and changed the Glide version of library.! because They were using old versions!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using the currently latest version: 4.7.1

The error is likely to cause because of your dependencies, to me, downgrading the Glide version to 4.3.1 worked fine.

```
    implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
```

By the way, use the term `implementation`, rather than `compile` as it will be removed this year.

This solution might not work for you, because your version is already *4.2.0*

But anyway, Hope it works!

Comment: This is not helping me.

Comment: I got the same error using the currently latest version: 4.9.0
Downgrade to 4.7.1 worked!

Answer (score -1):

after migrating android to androidx 
and upgrading the gradle to newer version I had some problems with glide..

after trying version one by one... this version was the only one that works for me..

recommending on glide 4.8.0

with the newer and with the elders i had some problems.. maybe this version will works for you too..

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

maybe you will find here some info that might help..
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases

Comment: The problem was not my gradle. It was library's problem. I downloaded the library and changed the library Glide's version!

Answer (score -1):

You are facing this error because **MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4** using old glide version and your project using newer version. When Gradle builds your project, It uses a newer version of Gradle and **MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4** will crash internally. You can confirm this in External libraries of project in android studio. Use same version of glide will solve this problem. Either downgrade your project's version of check latest version of MultipleImageSelect.